# How load a local CSS file to specific site

Tags: userscripts

I'm looking for a way to make the function GM_addStyle add CSS straight from the @resource on my local drive (I use macOS). My goal is to speed up the development of this CSS file.

Right now I'm copy&pasting changes to Tampermonkey > saving the userstyle & reloading the page.

Not working:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name my style
// @version 0.1
// @description a few friendliness tweaks
// @author thomas
// @match http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @resource my_style file:///Users/thomas/style.css
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

(function() { 'use strict'; GM_addStyle(GM_getResourceText('my_style')); })();
```

Thanks

Comment: Is your underlying question about live reloading css for web-development purposes or is it specific to tampermonkey?

Comment: Both, kind of. If Tampermonkey could load this local CSS file, I wouldn't have to copy&paste each time I make a change.

Comment: why do you not look into other solutions for live reloading code/css? Webpack is one solution, but that might be over kill. Parceljs should provide you with live reloading without almost no config required, http://parceljs.org/

Comment: Not looking for live-reloading. I'm not working on a web app. I'm working on a Tampermonkey script that has lots of CSS tamper-work for a specific web app that cannot be edited.